# Flash Component show alt image instead of flash-animation in aem publish

Tags: aem

I'm using aem 6.0 instance. I just put flash component on page. On authoring everything is ok. On publish there is js exception occurs:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CQ is not defined
```

Is it necessary to include `cq.shared` lib?

Comment: Does the component work on the sample Geometrixx site? If it does, what's different between your site & that one? You need to provide more background info to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @anotherdave said,

> Does the component work on the sample Geometrixx site? If it does, what's different between your site & that one? You need to provide more background info to your question

I have checked geometrix site, it is have the following scriplet, wich include libraries:

```
com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager htmlMgr = 
sling.getService(com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager.class); 
if (htmlMgr != null) { 
     htmlMgr.writeIncludes(slingRequest, out, ........);
}
```

I just add necessary libs, and component works correctly